# ImageView has excessive vertical padding

Tags: android, android-layout, padding, scaling, android-imageview

I noticed that when displaying images in my `ImageView` that are automatically scaled down to fit into the window, they are adding at least 50% added padding above and below the image even though the scaled `ImageView` image takes up less than 1/4 of the visible screen.  When images that fit without resizing are shown, this doesn't happen.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

If it matters, the top level layout is a `LinearLayout` containing a `ScrollView` that includes the following `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to tell Android that you want the `View`'s bounds to change after the scaling is done.

This is done using [`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds).

Comment: Damn, another irritating Android bug.  According to the documentation, this is to preserve the aspect ratio of the drawable.  The image is already scaled with the correct aspect ratio, it's just padding the top and bottom as if it weren't scaled.  Either way, why the hell wouldn't they have this setting default to "true"?

Comment: Yeah, it also preserves the aspect ratio of the container. And it's set as `false` so that unnecessary whitespace isn't left unhandled around images that are scaled by one direction... or at least, that's my guess. ;)

Comment: Here's a related Android issue for posterity:  [Possible ImageView measure bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20296),

Comment: Good link! Romain Guy knows his stuff, so I guess it's not a bug after all.